# Why were two of my questions deleted by "community" with no reason or notification given?

Tags: support

Two of my questions (https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/12721/14406, https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/12697/14406) were recently deleted by "community". I was not given a notification about this apart from that I was returned 4 reputation without explanation, so I assumed it must've been these and lo and behold they were found in my deleted questions.

Why were they deleted like this without a reason or notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I should've looked at the link the banner pointed to: https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions